# How to read a multiple raster files from web in R?

Tags: html, r, raster, netcdf4

I wanted to display in R (without downloading to my computer) .nc files from a server with free access on the internet. I used this code below, but I can't find a good command to read all the files.
Can someone help me to improve my code please!

```
url <- "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/avhrr-land-normalized-difference-vegetation-index/access/1981/"
f="*.nc"
if (!file.exists(f)) download.file(file.path(url, f), f, mode="wb")



trying URL 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/avhrr-land-normalized-difference-vegetation-index/access/1981//*.nc'
Error in download.file(file.path(url, f), f, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/avhrr-land-normalized-difference-vegetation-index/access/1981//*.nc'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(file.path(url, f), f, mode = "wb") :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/avhrr-land-normalized-difference-vegetation-index/access/1981//*.nc': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to display under R all the images in the 1981 folder! is there any idea please!